# C# Mysql UTF8 Encoding

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a mysql database with utf8_general_ci encoding ,

i'm connecting to the same database with php using utf-8 page and file encode and no problem
but when connection mysql with C# i have letters like this ØºØ²Ø©

i editit the connection string to be like this

```
server=localhost;password=root;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=mydatabase;Character Set=utf8
```

but the same problem .

Comment: If you find a solution I will be impressed - I tried UTF8 encoding with no luck as well, I ended up having to resort to stripping those characters prior to adding to the database by doing a `string.Replace("\xFFFD", "");`, which obviously causes issues when someone has a minuscule as part of their name.

Comment: One thing I had considered was looking at alternative char sets to UTF8 - for example UTF16, or UTF8-swedish.

Comment: 'Mojibake' is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 39):

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; CharSet=utf8;
```

Note! Use lower case value utf8 and not upper case UTF8 as this will fail.

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: this was the connection string generated by the wizard

Comment: Ahh well, check out the link i provided, it has all the MySQL Connection Strings

Comment: i checked it , when using small utf data are returned in the correct encoding , when it's UTF no data returned

Comment: I search for a solution for 2 days!   simple is the best , Thanks!

Comment: I've been searching for a while with no results... Thanks!!! (My problem was with some accentuated characters)

Answer (score 5):

could you try:

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=x xx;Pwd=xxxx;charset=utf8;"
```

Edit: I got a new idea:

```
//To encode a string to UTF8 encoding
string source = "hello world";
byte [] UTF8encodes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);

//get the string from UTF8 encoding
string plainText = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UTF8encodes);
```

good luck

more info about this technique http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/BF68DDD8-3D95-4478-B84A-6570A2E20AE5

Comment: The GetBytes->GetString didn't do anything for me with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to use the "utf8mb4" character set for the column in order to support 4 byte characters like this: "λ "

The utf8 charset only supports 1-3 bytes per character and thus can't support all unicode characters.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html for more details.

Comment: `ØºØ²Ø©` is Mojibake for `غزة`, which can be represented in either utf8 or utf8mb4.  Still, it is generally better to shoot for utf8mb4.

Answer (score 1):

CHARSET should be uppercase

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=x xx;Pwd=xxxx;CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some come here later.

I needed to create a Seed method using Mysql with EF6, to load a SQL file. After running it I got weird characters on database like ? replacing é, ó, á

**SOLUTION:** 
Make sure I read the file using the right charset: UTF8 on my case.

```
     var path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
     var sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "../../Migrations/SeedData/scripts/sectores.sql", Encoding.UTF8);
```

And then M.Shakeri reminder:

CHARSET=utf8 on cxn string in web.config. Using CHARSET as uppercase and utf8 lowercase.

Hope it helps.

R.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found, but haven't had the opportunity to really browse is the collation charts available here: http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/

This will show you which characters are part of a given MySQL collation so you can pick the best option for your dataset.

Comment: that was a bit helpful it's latin1_general_ci how this would be useful ?

Comment: If you set your collation to latin1_general_ci in mySQL you should be able to pull the correct data from your database in C# and PHP - worth a shot anyways

Answer (score 0):

Setting the charset in the connection string refers to the charset of the queries sent to the server.  It does not affect the *results* returned from the server.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

One way I have found to specify the charset from the client is to run this after opening the connection.

`set character_set_results='utf8';`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
"datasource=xxx;port=3306;username=xxx;password=xxx;database=xxx;charset=utf8mb4"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).