# How to save Hindi character In MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working in a Window Application(C#) and database is MySQL. In Application I am fetching gmail inbox and save it into Database. But my problem is that when I am using Insert Query in code `Subject` or `message` column showing message in Hindi but When save in Database it's showing character `????????` like this. I have already changed everything in UTF-8 in MySQL.

And when I Insert same using MySQL editor it saves in Hindi Font. That's a weird situation for me as I am new to MySQL.

```
  foreach (ImapMessageInfo message in messages)
        {

            InsertMail(message.UniqueId, message.Sender.ToString(), message.To.ToString(), message.Subject.Trim(), message.Date.LocalTime, client.GetMailMessage(message.SequenceNumber).BodyText);

        }



 public void InsertMail(string uid, string from, string to, string subject, DateTime datetime, string message)
    {
        try
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unique_id", uid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sender", from);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reciever", to);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", datetime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail_status", "unread");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            string query = "Insert Ignore into gmail_inbox(unique_id,sender,reciever,subject,date,message,mail_status) values (@unique_id,@sender,@reciever,@subject,@date,@message,@mail_status) ";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't save fonts in a database, you save characters. How are you inserting? Where's the C# code? How are you trying to view the database after inserting?

Comment: Yeah sorry My mean was character. Using Select QUery

Comment: using Select * from table;

Answer (score 1):

Check the character set and collation of your database. Using UTF8 should allow you to save these correctly and to display them correctly. Also make sure that when you initialize the connection you set the connection character set as utf8, otherwise other errors can occur.

Basicaly you need to make sure that the column/table and the connection character set is utf8, and after that you should be fine inserting the data you want.

Comment: Hello Xnoise, I checked all things.

Comment: character_set_client, utf8                                            
character_set_connection, utf8
character_set_database, utf8
character_set_filesystem, binary
character_set_results, utf8
character_set_server, utf8
character_set_system, utf8
character_sets_dir, C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\share\charsets\

Comment: Where are you getting the ???? Using the mysql client? Please describe where exactly where the problem appears.

Comment: When I Insert value through c# its show hindi character like ??????   but when I use same thing in SQL Editor its working fine.

Comment: Ok. Try issuing this before any query: SET NAMES UTF8; and then run the query. Also, the ??? characters: are they in the mysql client, in the software that you use for looking at the database, in the browser, etc. Depending on where you see these results multiple things can cause this, so let's try to reduce the problem a bit.

Comment: Character Also show ???? in software after reading datbase. But Manually update in My sql (using editor) its works fine. It means My sql supports Hindi Font and also when we pass value thats also show in Hindi then where is the problem. I use SET NAMES UTF8; but nothing happens.

Comment: Unfortunatelly at this point seems to be a problem related to C#, but i have no experience there unfortunatelly. The connection and the rest of the settings seem to be fine, and if adding from the database management software also works fine, then it can only be a problem of C# unless i missed something obvious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689129/c-sharp-mysql-utf8-encoding but not sure.

Comment: I also thinking may be problem in C#.

Comment: Any Way Thanks for Your valuable Time.

Comment: No problem. Please put the solution in here if you find it.

Comment: First thing I'd check if I get question marks is that the font used to display the characters supports the required glyphs. Hindi is certainly not widely supported in average fonts.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set table Collation to utf8_unicode_ci using below query

```
alter table <table_name> convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

2) You need to modify you Connection String and add Character Set=utf8
it should be like this

```
"User Id=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;Port=3306;Database=YourDatabaseName;Character Set=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// mytable=2 fields id(Auto increment),title(nvarchar(max))
string title = "बिलाल";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable values (N'" + title + "')", con);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Change collection `"utf8 - default collection"` in the table in my sql.

[image]

2. Add `"Character Set=utf8;"` into connection string.

   ```
   <appSettings>
       <add key="ConnString" value="Server=xxxxx; Port=3306; Database=books;Uid=xxxx; Pwd=xxxx; Convert Zero Datetime=True; Character Set=utf8;" />
   </appSettings>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## For each database:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

## For each table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

## For each column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

#update database properties
datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```