# Arabic in MySQL shows as?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I know this question was asked before I checked all other questions

[Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

and done what they told to do

I have change collation to utf8_general_ci and changed charset to utf8

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE MyTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

yet still get ????

I changed SP parameters to nvarchar and still ????

does one know what am I doing wrong here??

Comment: How exactly are you inserting the data…?

Comment: May well be a Duplicate of [UTF-8 All the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I send it from .Net web app to a MySQL SP

Comment: Then probably this…? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689242/476

Comment: @deceze yessss that was it.. thanks.. put it as an answer so i mark it

Comment: "Question marks" are covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored